# Intriguing Convergent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I fell upon this very interesting series in a textbook:
$$ S_n=\sum_{p=1}^n \frac {1}{n+p}$$ 
Although it resembles harmonic series, this series has a limit. 
 I managed to prove that the values of $S_n$ must exist in a particular interval for every integer $n$. Here we go:
$$ 1 ≤ p ≤ n $$
$$ 1+n ≤ p+n ≤ 2n $$
$$ \frac 1{2n} ≤\frac 1{n+p} ≤ \frac 1{n+1} $$
$$\sum_{p=1}^n \frac {1}{2n} ≤ \sum_{p=1}^n \frac {1}{n+p} ≤ \sum_{p=1}^n \frac {1}{n+1}$$
$$ \frac {n}{2n} ≤ S_n ≤ \frac {n}{n+1} $$
Finally
$$ \frac {1}{2} ≤ \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n ≤ 1 $$
I also tried computing some values for example: 
$ S_{10}= 0.66877... $  ,  $ S_{100}= 0.69065... $   and   $ S_{1000}= 0.69289...$
So it is obvious that the series are slowly converging towards a particular value, but what is it? 
I feel like Bernoulli (with all modesty) who found out that the Basel series is less than a number so I'm waiting for the Euler to discover the true limit.

 Please help me and make it as simple as possible.

Comment: it converges to $ln(2)$ if this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me how I find this result?

Comment: see the answers provided, i don't have time unfortunately sorry.

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define the harmonic numbers

$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

Your series can be represented by

$$H_{2n}-H_n=\frac1{n+1}+\cdots+\frac1{2n}$$

And since $\lim H_n-\log(n)=\gamma$, we know $\lim H_n-\log(n)-\gamma=0$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} H_{2n}-H_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} H_{2n}-\log(2n)-\gamma-(H_n-\log(n)-\gamma)+\log(2)=0+0+\log(2)$$

So that your series converges to $\log(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, one can proceed as

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}\frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+x} = \log 2. $$

Answer (score 0):

Just as vrugtehagel answered,$$S_n=\sum_{p=1}^n \frac {1}{n+p}=H_{2 n}-H_n$$ Now, if you use the asymptotics $$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$you should get $$S_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Similarly, considering $$T_n=\sum_{p=1}^n \frac {1}{an+p}=H_{(a+1) n}-H_{a n}$$ assuming $a \gt 0$, the expansion would be $$T_n=\log\left(1+\frac 1a\right)-\frac{1}{2 a (a+1) n}+\frac{2 a+1}{12 a^2 (a+1)^2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$